# Confusion about O((log n)²) vs O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, logarithm

I can't find anything good on the internet explaining what O((log *n*)<sup>2</sup>) is equal to. I think it's equal to O(log *n*), by the following argument:

- O(log (log *n*)<sup>2</sup>)
  = O(log (log *n* · log *n*))
  = O(log log *n* + log log *n*)
  = O(2 log log *n*)
  = O(log log *n*)
- Removing a 'log' from both sides gives O((log *n*)<sup>2</sup>) = O(log *n*).

Is that valid?

Comment: I think the mistake in your logic is dropping the 2. The LHS is really `exp(2*log(log(n)))` and you can't just drop the 2 from that.

Answer (score 4):

The argument you’re proposing here is an interesting one, but unfortunately it doesn’t work. To see why, let’s “prove” that O(n<sup>137</sup>) = O(n). To do so, notice that

> O(log n<sup>137</sup>)
>
> = O(137 log n)
>
> = O(log n).

So dropping the logs from both sides gives us that O(n<sup>137</sup>) = O(n).

But of course, that can’t be right. And the reason why is that while it *is* the case that if f(n) = O(g(n)) then log n = O(log g(n)), it’s not generally true that log f(n) = O(log g(n)) implies f(n) = O(g(n)).

As to your initial question - it’s not the case that log<sup>2</sup> n = O(log n). In fact, for any function f that isn’t O(1), it’s not the case that f(n)<sup>2</sup> = O(f(n)).

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. However, wouldn't any function with a range between (-1,1) have the property of f(n)^2 = O(f(n))? Ex: f(n) =1/x and our domain is from (1,infinity). Functions like this are pretty much useless though for algorithm analysis, right?

Comment: Big-O notation is used differently in real analysis and in computer science. In computer science, we're looking for limits as n tends toward infinity. Usually (but not always) in analysis the limits tend toward zero. So this might just be an issue of the notation meaning slightly different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is bounded above by `2*log(N)` then `exp(A)` is bounded above by `exp(2*log(N))` which is larger than `exp(log(N))` = `N`.

Your logic falls apart where you drop the '2' before reapplying the exp().

Comment: I see, so my logic is essentially something like: e^(2*log(n)) = e^(log(n)) which isn't true because e^(2*log(n)) = e^(log(n)) * e^(log(n)) = n*n and e^(log(n)) = n, right?